# Create an Array of Object from an Array of Strings with Lodash

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, lodash

I have the following array;

```
["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"]
```

I want it to be like this;

```
[{ id: 0, name: "Test1" }, { id: 1, name: "Test2" }, { id: 2, name: "Test3" }]
```

Any Help?
I guess I should somehow use `_.object()` for this mission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) function is your friend:

```
_.map(array, function(item, index) {
    return { id: index, name: item };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using angular this should simply do the trick.

```
var newArray = [];
angular.forEach(myArray,function(item, key){
    newArray.push({id:key, name:item});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution does not require angular and is just based on lodash:

```
var newArray = [];

_.forEach(["Test1", "Test2", "Test3"], function (item, key) {
    newArray.push({
        id: key,
        name: item
    });
});
```